# Animating images on a xpage

Tags: xpages

I want to have a series of images slide into a section on a page.  Can anyone point me to a technique of doing that?

many thanks!
clem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a carousel - check out these jQuery plugins

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/06/jquery-carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use Dojo that comes with XPages, check out these links:

- http://davidjs.com/2011/01/fun-with-dojo-animation/
- https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/image/LightboxNano.html
- http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596516482/animation_and_special_effects.html
- http://almaer.com/blog/cleanup-of-manual-animation-via-dojo-animation

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Dojo Effects simple actions available with 8.5.3 UP1 and extlib.

[image: Dojo Effects simple actions]

Documentation here:

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDesignerXPagesExtensionLibrary.html#Simpleactions_dojoslideto